# How do you print certain words in a text file that are between commas?

Tags: python

Say I have a text file that says:

```
    this is part 1, this is part 2, this is part 3
    this is part 4, this is part 5, this is part 6
    this is part 7, this is part 8, this is part 9
```

How would I only print parts 1, 4, and 7 (the first section on a new line)?

This is about how far I have managed to get:

```
    fp = open("text", "r+")
    titles = fp.readlines()
    print(titles[0])
```

Comment: treat it like a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your text by newlines (`\n`) and then split on the comma. Since you only need the first element of the second split you will use index `0` to print those elements.

```
text = """this is part 1, this is part 2, this is part 3
this is part 4, this is part 5, this is part 6
this is part 7, this is part 8, this is part 9"""

for t in text.split("\n"):
    print t.split(',')[0]
```

Prints:

```
this is part 1
this is part 4
this is part 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Read all the lines into a list, then split on commas within a list comprehension, and get the first element of the split.

```
with open("text", "r") as fp:
    titles = [i.split(',')[0] for i in fp.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module.

The rows are arrays split by commas, so you can determine which element you're interested in for each row.

Since you want the first one, you'll do `print row[0]`

```
import csv

with open("blah.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader: # for each row
        print row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

readlines() makes a list of the lines, so titles[0] is just the first line (top row). What you seem to want is the first column. The function you need is split(), which will split a string on a certain character or word. You want to use `split(",")` on each line to split on the commas and indec it `[0]` to get the part before the first comma.

```
fp = open("text", "r+")
titles = fp.readlines()
for title in titles:
    print(title.split(",")[0])
```

Output:

```
this is part 1
this is part 4
this is part 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
text_file = open("filename.dat", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
print lines[0]
```